# Looking for a string inside a register

Tags: ansible

I’m running an API call in order to get indexes in Elastic – The output is saved inside a registry (index_list).

I want to run an additional job that runs only in case the policy name can be found in the register output – The solution I gave is not working (I’m guessing that I need to loop inside the registry on specific fields ) -

in the example below i have a policy ID named **what**

**API Call**

```
 - name: Get ISM_retention policy
  uri:
    url: http://elastic:9200/_opendistro/_ism/policies
    method: GET
    timeout: 180
    body_format: json
  register: index_list
```

**The debug condition that I’m trying to run –**
In the register output you can find the **u'policy_id': u'what'**

```
- debug:
    msg: hello
  when: “'what' in index_list”
```

**The register output**  - The policy ID is marked

MSG:

{u'status': 200, u'content_length': u'1919', u'cookies': {}, u'url': u'http://elastic:9200/_opendistro/_ism/policies', u'changed': False, u'elapsed': 0, u'failed': False, u'json': {u'total_policies': 3, u'policies': [{u'policy': {u'default_state': u'hot', u'description': u'policy for delete index', u'last_updated_time': 1667984798760, u'error_notification': None, u'states': [{u'transitions': [{u'conditions': {u'min_index_age': u'1d'}, u'state_name': u'delete'}], u'name': u'hot', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'open': {}}]}, {u'transitions': [], u'name': u'delete', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'delete': {}}]}], u'ism_template': [{u'index_patterns': [u'audit-*'], u'priority': 100, u'last_updated_time': 1667984798760}], u'schema_version': 15, u'policy_id': u'policy_1'}, u'_id': u'policy_1', u'_seq_no': 104149, u'_primary_term': 1}, {u'policy': {u'default_state': u'hot', u'description': u'kuku index retenation flow', u'last_updated_time': 1668061803458, u'error_notification': None, u'states': [{u'transitions': [{u'conditions': {u'min_index_age': u'1d'}, u'state_name': u'delete'}], u'name': u'hot', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'open': {}}]}, {u'transitions': [], u'name': u'delete', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'delete': {}}]}], u'ism_template': [{u'index_patterns': [u'kuku-*'], u'priority': 100, u'last_updated_time': 1668061803458}], u'schema_version': 15, u'policy_id': u'policy_kuku'}, u'_id': u'policy_kuku', u'_seq_no': 143284, u'_primary_term': 1}, {u'policy': {u'default_state': u'hot', u'description': u'what index retenation flow', u'last_updated_time': 1668074528411, u'error_notification': None, u'states': [{u'transitions': [{u'conditions': {u'min_index_age': u'1d'}, u'state_name': u'delete'}], u'name': u'hot', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'open': {}}]}, {u'transitions': [], u'name': u'delete', u'actions': [{u'retry': {u'count': 3, u'delay': u'1m', u'backoff': u'exponential'}, u'delete': {}}]}], u'ism_template': [{u'index_patterns': [u'what-*'], u'priority': 100, u'last_updated_time': 1668074528411}], u'schema_version': 15, **u'policy_id': u'what'**}, u'_id': u'what', u'_seq_no': 150078, u'_primary_term': 1}]}, u'content_type': u'application/json; charset=UTF-8', u'msg': u'OK (1919 bytes)', u'redirected': False, u'cookies_string': u''}

Answer (score 1):

Given the UTF-8 data in the file for testing

```bash
shell> cat index_list.json
```

> {status: 200, content_length: 1919, cookies: {}, url: http://elastic:9200/_opendistro/_ism/policies, changed: False, elapsed: 0, failed: False, json: {total_policies: 3, policies: [{policy: {default_state: hot, description: policy for delete index, last_updated_time: 1667984798760, error_notification: None, states: [{transitions: [{conditions: {min_index_age: 1d}, state_name: delete}], name: hot, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, open: {}}]}, {transitions: [], name: delete, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, delete: {}}]}], ism_template: [{index_patterns: [audit-], priority: 100, last_updated_time: 1667984798760}], schema_version: 15, policy_id: policy_1}, _id: policy_1, _seq_no: 104149, _primary_term: 1}, {policy: {default_state: hot, description: kuku index retenation flow, last_updated_time: 1668061803458, error_notification: None, states: [{transitions: [{conditions: {min_index_age: 1d}, state_name: delete}], name: hot, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, open: {}}]}, {transitions: [], name: delete, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, delete: {}}]}], ism_template: [{index_patterns: [kuku-], priority: 100, last_updated_time: 1668061803458}], schema_version: 15, policy_id: policy_kuk}, _id: policy_kuk, _seq_no: 143284, _primary_term: 1}, {policy: {default_state: hot, description: what index retenation flow, last_updated_time: 1668074528411, error_notification: None, states: [{transitions: [{conditions: {min_index_age: 1d}, state_name: delete}], name: hot, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, open: {}}]}, {transitions: [], name: delete, actions: [{retry: {count: 3, delay: 1m, backoff: exponential}, delete: {}}]}], ism_template: [{index_patterns: [what-*], priority: 100, last_updated_time: 1668074528411}], schema_version: 15, policy_id: what}, _id: what, _seq_no: 150078, _primary_term: 1}]}, content_type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, msg: OK (1919 bytes), redirected: False, cookies_string: }

Read the file and create the dictionary index_list

```yaml
    - include_vars:                                                                           
        file: index_list.json                                                                 
        name: index_list
```

gives

```yaml
  index_list:
    changed: false
    content_length: 1919
    content_type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    cookies: {}
    cookies_string: null
    elapsed: 0
    failed: false
    json:
      policies:
      - _id: policy_1
        _primary_term: 1
        _seq_no: 104149
        policy:
          default_state: hot
          description: policy for delete index
          error_notification: None
          ism_template:
          - index_patterns:
            - audit-
            last_updated_time: 1667984798760
            priority: 100
          last_updated_time: 1667984798760
          policy_id: policy_1
          schema_version: 15
          states:
          - actions:
            - open: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: hot
            transitions:
            - conditions:
                min_index_age: 1d
              state_name: delete
          - actions:
            - delete: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: delete
            transitions: []
      - _id: policy_kuk
        _primary_term: 1
        _seq_no: 143284
        policy:
          default_state: hot
          description: kuku index retenation flow
          error_notification: None
          ism_template:
          - index_patterns:
            - kuku-
            last_updated_time: 1668061803458
            priority: 100
          last_updated_time: 1668061803458
          policy_id: policy_kuk
          schema_version: 15
          states:
          - actions:
            - open: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: hot
            transitions:
            - conditions:
                min_index_age: 1d
              state_name: delete
          - actions:
            - delete: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: delete
            transitions: []
      - _id: what
        _primary_term: 1
        _seq_no: 150078
        policy:
          default_state: hot
          description: what index retenation flow
          error_notification: None
          ism_template:
          - index_patterns:
            - what-*
            last_updated_time: 1668074528411
            priority: 100
          last_updated_time: 1668074528411
          policy_id: what
          schema_version: 15
          states:
          - actions:
            - open: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: hot
            transitions:
            - conditions:
                min_index_age: 1d
              state_name: delete
          - actions:
            - delete: {}
              retry:
                backoff: exponential
                count: 3
                delay: 1m
            name: delete
            transitions: []
      total_policies: 3
    msg: OK (1919 bytes)
    redirected: false
    status: 200
    url: http://elastic:9200/_opendistro/_ism/policies
```

---

Q: ***"Run task if the policy name can be found in the register output."***

A: Declare the list

```yaml
policies: "{{ index_list.json.policies|map(attribute='_id')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
policies:
  - policy_1
  - policy_kuk
  - what
```

Test the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: hello
      when: "'what' in policies"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    policies: "{{ index_list.json.policies|map(attribute='_id')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: index_list.json
        name: index_list

    - debug:
        var: index_list

    - debug:
        var: policies

    - debug:
        msg: hello
      when: "'what' in policies"
```